# Android - my recyclerview is not showing data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am a junior programmer here trying to create an MVVM application in Android using Kotlin. I am trying to create a housing app that retrieves houses from an API then shows them in a recycler view.

The problem is that my recycler view is empty. I do have an adapter and maybe there is something going wrong. I believe they're not being paired together correctly

Anyway, I'm going to show my fragment class.

```
class HousesFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var factory: HousesViewModelFactory
private lateinit var viewModel: HousesViewModel
private lateinit var rv: RecyclerView
private lateinit var adapter: HousesAdapter


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.houses_fragment, container, false)
}


override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    val api = HouseApi()
    val repo = HouseRepo(api)
    factory = HousesViewModelFactory(repo)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(HousesViewModel::class.java)
    rv = view?.findViewById(R.id.rvHouses) ?: return

    //use the adapter
    viewModel.getHouses()
    viewModel.houses.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { houses ->
        rv.also {

            it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            it.adapter = HousesAdapter(houses, this)
            it.setHasFixedSize(true)

            rv.adapter = it.adapter


        }
    })


}
```

}

I think that this code in particular is causing the problem

```
rv.also {

            it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            it.adapter = HousesAdapter(houses, this)
            it.setHasFixedSize(true)

            rv.adapter = it.adapter


        }
```

the reason why I say that is because this code is responsible for matching the recyclerview with the adapter.

I'll explain other things I tried. I tried to implement other people's code and see how their's works. I did so by going on Youtube and checking a bunch of tutorials. Nothing has worked so far, and it's not ideal to do this. I'm trying my best to get past this error. Looking at examples is the best I could do. I'm a junior programmer and don't yet possess the skill of debugging everything on my own

Thank you

EDIT:

here's the adapter:

```
class HousesAdapter(
    private val houses: List<HouseItem>,
    housesFragment: HousesFragment
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HousesAdapter.HousesViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount() = houses.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        HousesViewHolder(
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.recyclerview_house,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HousesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.recyclerviewHouseBinding.house = houses[position]
    }

    inner class HousesViewHolder(

        val recyclerviewHouseBinding: RecyclerviewHouseBinding

    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(recyclerviewHouseBinding.root)
}
```

[image]

[image]

The fix:

Turns out I didn't put textviews inside the cardview. I totally forgot about that step and it was my mistake. Hopefully this post can serve as a reminder to others to populate their cardviews too and make sure it's filled. This'll also serve as a reminder for me. Very stupid mistake indeed, but now I'm sure I won't repeat it.

A big thanks to everyone who commented

Comment: We are going to need to see the adapters code first and foremost

Comment: Ok no problem chief

Comment: Can you debug and confirm that the `ViewModel` returns data into `houses` within the `observe` method?

Comment: I am looking into that right now Zain

Comment: it shows me that my adapter is null. that must be some type of hint

Comment: Can you remove this `rv.adapter = it.adapter`?

Comment: I removed that line and it still doesn't work =(

Comment: can you share your cardview XML file, please?

Comment: It turns out my XML was faulty. Thanks for the tip Mehran. I thought it was the logic that was faulty. Thanks to everyone. Turns out I was missing the textviews in the cardview. Very stupid mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few fixes to make:

1. You call `getHouses` first and then observe the data. Where as you should observe the data and then call `getHouses`.
2. Only set the `RecyclerView`s `layoutManager` and `setHasFixedSize` once.
3. Remove  `rv.adapter = it.adapter` that seems redundant due to this line: `it.adapter = HousesAdapter(houses, this)`.
4. This line seems a bit much `rv = view?.findViewById(R.id.rvHouses) ?: return` so if `view` or `RecyclerView` is `null` we return, something tells me this should never be the case.

Here would be an example with all my recommended changes made:

```
    rv = view!!.findViewById(R.id.rvHouses)
    rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true)
    viewModel.houses.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { houses ->
        rv.adapter = HousesAdapter(houses, this)
    })
    viewModel.getHouses()
```

5. Your `onBindViewHolder` method seems suspect, looking at [examples](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#advanced_binding) you should have something similar to:

   ```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BindingHolder, position: Int) {
        item: T = items.get(position)       
        holder.binding.setVariable(BR.item, item);            
        holder.binding.executePendingBindings();
    }
   ```

Comment: Hello David, I'm going to try this out now. Thank you so much for your answer. I'll get back with an answer soon hopefully

Comment: Sadly enough that didn't do the trick. I still get this warning: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Also if after you have updated the code as per my example and it still does not work, put a breakpoint on the line `rv.adapter = HousesAdapter(houses, this)`. Is the breakpoint ever hit? Does `houses ` contain any items?

Comment: Hello David. I'm getting close. The houses array is indeed filled, just sadly enough not showing in the cards within the recyclerview. The house array has 10 items inside and does indeed hold the attributes that I requested, like bathrooms and bedrooms. I'll try to attach a screenshot of it all to show you

Comment: Cool lol do you like using `aslo` so much if so you are using it wrong when you use `also` you can simply use the passed in item `it` but as my example showed there is no need for that.. sorry thays my OCD. Also it seems the RecyclerView is showing the cards for each house, but in your code I.e. `ViewHolder` i see nowhere where you actually set the house data to any xml or ViewHolder... that doesn't seem right

Comment: See here for more (scroll down to the example of adapter and its viewholders): https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#implement-adapter you can see it created the viewholder with a specific xml and then binds the view and the data explicitly not sure what library or architecture you are using but it seems like magic at this point. Lol so I assume your "magic" binding of viewholder ad the data isn't happening...

Comment: I read up on DataBindingUtil and even there in the example they are still specifically setting the data to the viewholders layout https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#advanced_binding

Comment: Hello David, I have implemented the code example and Android is telling me it doesn't recognise what "item" is. I was following a youtube tutorial on MVVM, so I followed someone's code and when things don't work, I'm left rather clueless on what the problem is. I'm gonna try further debugging now

Comment: Hello David. turns out the xml was faulty, silly me. I didn't put the textviews in the cardview. Very dumb mistake. I've voted your answer as the best anyway, you helped me and I appreciate it